# How to get list of unused images in the image family

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am following [google's image management](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/image-management-best-practices) document to create application GCE images. I am setting image families to pick latest image from. However I am struggling to get sorted list of older images for cleanup.

```
gcloud compute images describe-from-family test-packerized-centos7-base
```

returns latest image

```
{
    "archiveSizeBytes": "883668032",
    "creationTimestamp": "2018-04-25T23:25:36.137-07:00",
    "description": "Created by Packer",
    "diskSizeGb": "20",
    "family": "test-packerized-centos7-base",
    "id": "6938962862287932976",
    "kind": "compute#image",
    "labelFingerprint": "42WmSpB8rSM=",
    "licenseCodes": [
    "1000207"
     ],
   "name": "wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-3-1524723518",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/global/images/wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-3-1524723518",
   "sourceDisk": "https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/my_project/zones/us-central1-a/disks/packer-5ae16f3e-13c6-0d93-da79-2f6e81f88fec",
  "sourceDiskId": "5923696438202388910",
  "sourceType": "RAW",
  "status": "READY"
}
```

However, when I list all the images in the project and grep with family name I can see all older images still in ready state.

```
gcloud compute images list | grep test-packerized-centos7-base
wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-1-1523048775 test-packerized-centos7-base READY
wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-1-1523050176 test-packerized-centos7-base READY
wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-2-1524258996 test-packerized- centos7-base READY
wp-centos7-base-bbaelish-shenanigans-2-1524259307 test-packerized-centos7-base READY
```

I know I have to deprecate the old images, however I am struggling to get sorted list of old images. I want to be mark last 5 images as deprecated and last 3 images after that as obsolete.

I have tried to use [Jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) filters to get sorted list.

```
gcloud compute images list --format json | jq '.[] | select(.family == "test-packerized-centos7-base") | sort_by(.creationTimestamp)'
```

However it returns following error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:4622): Cannot index string with string "creationTimestamp"
```

Anyone knows simple ways to get list of older images in "Image-families".
I assume google is maintaining the order somewhere, since when I delete latest image in the family it automatically points to older one.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to sort the list of images, you will have to run the `gcloud images list` command and apply the [specific filters](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list) to sort the images by date.

The [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/list) that you would have to run is:

```
$ gcloud compute images list --format="value(NAME)" --filter="[sorting-filter]"
```

Where `[sorting-filter]` will be a filter that sorts the images by the creation date.

For help on how to write filters, and how to use them, you may consult this [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters). Basically, you would just have to find the right filter. Since it is a specific filter, and the question is really unique to your use case, you would have to read through the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your query. As you are trying to fetch the list of images on the basis of 'Creation Time', you can use this command below.

```
gcloud compute images list --format="table(name,creationTimestamp.date(tz=LOCAL))"
```

But if you trying to sort this further in the basis of name, you can use grep.